# Linking Xcode 9 with MongoDB?

Tags: ios, xcode, mongodb

I created a project in Xcode 9 with Swift 4 and I have a mongo database through compose hosted on a galaxy meteor server.

I'm trying to access information from the database (eg. `db.checkpoints.findOne({_id: ""})`) to use in the app and trying to export some data from the app to the database. I need to pull information from the database into instances of an object I created called PDI and I need to send data from these instance back to the database.

I have never worked with databases before so I don't even know where to start with connecting my Xcode project with mongodb, any help would be great.

This is my PDI class that I need to send to the db:

```
import Foundation

class PDI { //**************THESE VARIABLES NEED TO SEND BACK TO THE DB***************
    var initialFuelConsumption: Double!
    var finalFuelConsumption: Double!
    var name: String!
    var OMMain: String!
    var OMSupp: String!
    var OMFitting: String!
    var OMCemos: String!
    var OMTeraTrack: String!
    var OMProfiCam: String!
    //C13[0] = CCA, C13[1] = Volt
    var C13 = [String()]
    var G001 = [String()]
    var G005 = [String()]
    var G004 = [String()]
    var MAN1 = [String()]
    var MAN2 = [String()]

    //0 = Incomplete, 1 = In Progress, 2 = Complete
    var status = 0
    var thisQuestion = 0
    //*********IMPORT QUESTION BANK DATA FROM MONGODB**********************
    var questionBank1 = []
```

Comment: Can you improve your formatting please?